# Problema em desalocação de memoria

Tags: c++, ponteiro, árvore-binária

Boa noite pessoal, venho enfrentando um problema referente a funcao free() no método destroy(), para desalocação de memória.

Apos inserir valores na arvore binaria em um primeiro momento eu até consigo desalocar através da funcao free(), porem se apos essa desalocação eu tentar imprimir a arvore ou tentar desalocar a memória novamente (Para testar se o sistema barra uma tentativa de imprimir uma arvore vazia ou uma nova desalocação de memória ), o sistema lança uma exceção e aborta.

Ja tentei várias coisas, mas como tenho pouco conhecimento sobre ponteiros nao obtive exito.

Agradeço desde já

```
#pragma once
class NodeTree {

 public:

  int value;
  NodeTree * left;
  NodeTree * right;

  NodeTree() {
    value = 0;
  }

};
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include "NodeTree.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BinaryTree {

public:

NodeTree * root;

BinaryTree() {
    root = NULL;
}


bool isEmpty(NodeTree * obj) {
    return obj == NULL;
}


void clean(int opcao) {

    if (isEmpty(root)) {
        cout << "A arvore ja esta vazia, nao e possivel esvazia-la novamente\n";
        return;
    }

    if (opcao == 1) {
        makeEmpty();
    }
    else {
        destroy(root);
        cout << "A arvore foi esvaziada e a memoria desalocada\n";
    }

}

void makeEmpty() {

    root = NULL;
    cout << "A arvore foi esvaziada\n";
    return;

}


void destroy(NodeTree * obj) {

    if (!isEmpty(obj)) {

        destroy(obj->left);

        destroy(obj->right);

        free(obj);

    }

    obj = NULL;

}



void insert(int num) {

    NodeTree * node = new NodeTree;
    node->value = num;

    insertNeatly(node, root);

}


void insertNeatly(NodeTree * node1, NodeTree *&root1) {

    if (root1 == NULL) {
        node1->left = NULL;
        node1->right = NULL;
        root1 = node1;
    }
    else {

        if (node1->value > root1->value) {
            insertInOrder(node1, root1->right);
        }
        else if (node1->value < root1->value) {
            insertInOrder(node1, root1->left);
        }
        else {
            return;
        }

    }

}



void print(NodeTree * obj) {

    if (obj == NULL)
        return;

    printInOrder(obj->left);

    cout << obj->value << " ";

    printInOrder(obj->right);

}


};
```

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

BinaryTree tree;
int sentinela = 0;
int numero;
int opcao;

while (sentinela != 4) {

    system("cls");
    cout << "Opcoes:\n\n1-Inserir ordenadamente\n2-Exibir em ordem\n3-Esvaziar arvore\n4-Sair\n\nOpcao desejada: ";
    cin >> sentinela;

    if (sentinela == 1) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Digite um numero: ";
        cin >> numero;
        tree.insert(numero);
    }

    if (sentinela == 2) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Exibicao em ordem: ";
        tree.print(tree.root);
        system("PAUSE");
    }


    if (sentinela == 3) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Escolha a opcao: 1-Esvaziar / 2- Esvaziar e desalocar memoria: ";
        cin >> opcao;
        tree.clean(opcao);
        system("PAUSE");
    }

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Você está alocando o *NodeTree* com o operador **new**, portanto, deverá desalocar com o operador [delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/). O *free()* é um comando da linguagem C, para desalocar a memória obtida pela função *malloc()*.

Comment: Obg pela ajuda Gomiero. Eu troquei free(obj) por delete(obj) no metodo destroy(), porem o problema ainda continua, nao sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acessar memória após ser desalocada, ou tentar desalocar duas vezes a mesma memória, resulta em **comportamento indefinido**. Sua função membro `BinaryTree::destroy` espera um `NodeTree *` como argumento, então não é possível alterar para onde a variável argumento está apontando, pois aqui você **passa por valor**, em vez de **passar por referência** (`obj = NULL` não altera o argumento, apenas o parâmetro).

Por exemplo:

```
void destroy(NodeTree *&obj) { //< Note a referência (&)
    if (!isEmpty(obj)) {
        destroy(obj->left); // Passa por referência
        destroy(obj->right); // Passa por referência
        delete obj;
        obj = NULL; // Agora sim, é possível alterar o argumento original.
    }
}
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, se eu modificar o cabeçalho de destroy, trocando isto void destroy(NodeTree * obj), por isto void destroy(NodeTre *& obj) eu conseguiria modificar para onde obj esta apontando apos o uso do free() ? Obg pela ajuda Mário !

Comment: @Rogi93, quase isso. Por exemplo, em `T &x = y;`, onde `T` é algum tipo qualquer, `x` é uma referência para a variável `y` do mesmo tipo `T`, e seria o valor dessa variável que você estaria alterando (no caso, essa variável seria `root`).

Comment: @Rogi93, a propósito, se você alocar espaço de armazenamento com `new`, é necessário desalocá-lo com `delete` (e não com `free()`), caso contrário o comportamento é indefinido.

Comment: Consegui resolver, coloquei o cabeçalho do metodo da seguinte forma: void destroy(NodeTree *&obj). Alem disso, modifiquei o free() por delete(). Muito obg pela ajuda Mário !!!